# Does a Lyapunov Function derivative necessarily vanish at each equilibrium point of the system?

Tags: control, stability

From Jean-Jacques E Slotine's book "APPLIED NONLINEAR CONTROL"

"several Lyapunov functions may exist for a given system, and therefore several associated invariant sets may be derived. The system then converges to the (necessarily non-empty) intersection of the invariant sets M, which may give a more precise result than that obtained from any of the Lyapunov functions taken separately. "

I understand that invariant sets can vary from a Lyapunov function to another, but does a Lyapunov function necessarily show a maximum or minimum at every equilibrium points of the system?

Comment: I would recommend that you post this question on one of; https://dsp.stackexchange.com/, https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://physics.stackexchange.com/ instead.. I think you are much more likely to find someone who can answer this question there.. Sadly in my experience the technical level on EE.SE is very low, more like a site for asking arduino-related questions, or questions about how to make an LED blink etc. questions with more depth tend to go unanswered for years...

Comment: I would also suggest asking in another SE site, possibly math.SE.

Answer (score 3):

Lyapunov functions are a tool used to demonstrate stability of systems. Imagine that we are interested only in demonstrating the stability of say, five equilibrium points out of say, total ten equilibrium points of a system. Then, we need to search for candidate Lyapunov functions which have maxima/minima at the  equilibrium points of interest only. Those candidate functions may or may not have maxima/minima at other equilibrium points. Proof of *local* stability about any given (isolated) equilibrium point doesn't depend on the behaviour of the selected Lyapunov function at other equilibrium points.

Answer (score 2):

That excerpt seems to be describing the same thing as

> Suppose a system is represented as 
> \$ \dot{x} = f ( x )\$ 
> where \$x\$ is the vector of variables, with 
> \$f ( 0 ) = 0 \$. 
> If a \$C^1\$ function \$V ( x )\$  can be found such that 
> \$ \dot{V} ( x ) \leq 0\$ for all \$x\$ (negative semidefinite), 
> then the set of accumulation points of any trajectory is contained in \$\mathcal{I}\$ where \$\mathcal{I}\$ is the union of complete trajectories contained entirely in the set \$ \{ x : \dot{V} ( x ) = 0 \} \$.

Source: [LaSalle's invariance principle, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaSalle%27s_invariance_principle)

In this case function \$V\$ is called a LaSalle function and is defined very similarly to the Lyapunov one. Now back to your question

> but does a Lyapunov function necessarily show a maximum or minimum at every equilibrium points of the system?

No.

You should focus on finding at least one Lyapunov function per equilibrium point. It would be considerably harder to find a single function that has local minima at every equilibrium points and it would not be that helpful.

Because if you analyze each equilibrium using simpler functions, say \$ V(x) = x^\top x \$, you could first find an appropriate Lyapunov function for that equilibrium and then even try to find others that give you a larger invariant set. With that you would have a  good approximation of the set \$\mathcal{I}\$ described  by LaSalle. It is worth noting that that set would have both equilibria and limit-cycles.